# Add label to an Gmail thread with only 1 message (the original message)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

When I send a quotation to a client, I want to write a script that will add a label to the email, easy. The catch is, I only want to add the label one time to the thread and then never again. I have another script that will take all the emails with that label and add a calendar reminder and will remove the label so it won't keep adding an event. The problem I am having is that when the client replies to that first email, the label is then reapplied, which causes yet another calendar event to be made. Is there any way to only add a label to a thread with a message count of 1? So in the case of the image below, the label should only apply to the second thread and not the first.

[Two threads, one with a single email, and one with 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voU75.png)

```
function QuoteReminder() {
  var reminderLabel = "STS Quotes", //Substitute your label here
      calendarName = "Quote Follow-ups", ////Substitute your Calendar name here
      label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(reminderLabel),
      threads = label.getThreads();

     if (threads.length > 0) {
       for (i in threads) {
         if (i.getMessageCount() == 1) {
          //get calendar by name
          var cals = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName);

          //This is run the next day around 9am, calendar invite will be created for 13 days form then to account for the next day
          var now = new Date().getTime();
          var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
          for (i in threads) {
            cals[0].createEvent(reminderLabel + '- '+ i.getFirstMessageSubject(),
             new Date(now+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)),
             new Date(now+(MILLIS_PER_DAY*13)+900000), {description: i.getPermalink()});
      }
      //Remove the label from the mails to avoid duplicate event creation on next run 
      label.removeFromThreads(threads);
         }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Sorry! Just added it. The code above assumes the label exists already and is adding the calendar reminder to any thread with the label. Originally I was looking for threads = 1 message with the label and had issues. So I thought maybe it would be easier if I went "up a level" to where the labels were added but had the same issue where I need to look for threads with only 1 message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

I cannot provide you a copy-paste solution since I have not seen your code and do not even know which programming language your are using, but

> there is the method [Users.threads: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) which returns you all the
>   messages of a thread.

So, you can incorporate a simple `if` statement to verify either the length of the message array is bigger than 1 and run the rest of you code accordingly.

### UPDATE:

- For retrieving the number of messages in a thread in Apps Script, you can use the method [`getMessageCount()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getmessagecount)
- This message needs to be applied to a single thread
- The method [`label.getThreads()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getthreads) returns you an array of threads
- To access single elements of the thread array you need to address them with their position in the array, e.g. `threads[0]`, `threads[1]` or - in a loop `threads[i]`

**In your case:**

you need to modify `if (i.getMessageCount() == 1) {...` to `if (threads[i].getMessageCount() == 1) {...`.

Otherwise, the `if` statement just verifies either he counter variable `i` is equal to `1` - which will always be the case in one of the iterations if `threads.length > 0`

Comment: Thanks! I just put the code up there. My apologies it wasn't there originally. This code was written to assume the label was there and I was having issues. Which is why I thought of going "up a level" where the label was added. Still, the same problem existed where I need to only look for threads with 1 message.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your problem is, given that you already using the method `getMessageCount()`. So within the statement `if (i.getMessageCount() == 1) {...` you just need to add `label.addToThread(i);`

Comment: The message count is not working. It still pulls all the threads with that search query regardless if there is 1 message or 5 messages.

Comment: I see. The problem is in your way to iterate over the threads - I updated my answer.